# Publish to azure option not visible in visual studio 2017

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I have an instance of visual studio 2017 in which azure functions are developing, strangely i stopped seeing, publish to azure option in the publish targets window and also in create new profile window.

If i open any of my other azure functions project in vs 2017, the window is seen correctly.

What could be different only for this case?[image]

Comment: well ,strangely my function app was missing functions sdk!! hence i was not seeing right publish outputs. after i installed Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Functions  it all worked

Comment: You could add it as an answer that will help more communities.

Answer (score 4):

(Copying comment into an actual answer for the community to see)

> well ,strangely my function app was missing functions sdk!! hence i was not seeing right publish outputs. **after i installed Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Functions it all worked**

Comment: Alas not the solution for me :(